# About php login and database storing

Tags: php, database

I want to keep track of the users that are logged in to the site.

I created table named `userlogininfo`. It will store 4-5 columns of login like time, ip address, browsers.

Will there be problem if there are thousands of users and they log many time and database will be very hard to manage and there will be millions for records ?

Comment: Pls share some of your works.

Comment: creating meta ..but there are many items in database? will it create any problem?

Comment: Could you rewrite your question to be more specific?

Comment: completly rewritten hope it help @773

Comment: There may be millions of records, if you get lots of users, or your page exists for a long time. that's normal, provided you don't make it too complicated, most SQL db's should manage well enough that you won't have to worry until you get enough users to afford to make a better solution. If you're worried about bloat, consider deleting records in a scheduled manner, or after a certain expiry (for example, delete all history more than 2 months old)

Comment: @serakfalcon thank you for the info..i was just searching for it ... i wonder why people asking my what have you don't so far :v

Comment: @Joanny it's because SO exists to help people troubleshoot programming questions, usually specific bits of code that they are stuck on, and a question like yours doesn't quite fit with that scope, since it's more theoretical in nature. To be honest, it might fit better with http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will there be problem if there are thousands of users and they log many time and database will be very hard to manage and there will be millions for records ?

It depends on the bandwidth and disk space provided by your hosting solution. Is there an inherent problem with storing millions of records and serving millions of people a webpage? No.

Comment: it means there will be no problem if there are billions of table in  database? and php will function problem to retrieve them from database?

Comment: [MySQL has no limit on the number of tables allowed on a database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html). And PHP is scalable -- it will work whether you have 3 users or billions.